# Is this a good way to put scrolling social bar on my website?

Tags: css, scroll, css-position

I'm coding my own scrolling social bar but i'm nut sure about method I'm using. As you can see on the pic above, I had put a wider grey div inside the narrower content div. Then I've set grey's one a css to make it's z-index less than the content z-index. It works ok and following content once I scroll the website but my question is - is this a good method to place a bar like this? Maybe there is an easier solution and better for browsers compatibility, isn't it?

Sincerely,
Matt

[image: http://i.imgur.com/eMrKJCa.jpg]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just have the size of the `DIV` cut down to less space and than make it `postion:fixed` so that it moves with the scroll.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xeemez/PjMcz/)

HTML

```
<div id='div1' align='center'>
    <span id='grey'>Like</span><br>Tweet<br><span id='grey'>Share</span>
</div>
<div id='div2' align='center'>Content</div>
```

CSS

```
#div1 {
    position:fixed;
    top:30px;
    left:5px;
    background:yellow;
    height:60px;
    width:50px;
    border:4px ridge black;
}
#div2 {
    height:800px;
    width:200px;
    background:orange;
    margin-left:60px;
}
#grey {
    background:grey;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you position the "like tweet share" div (I guess) relative to content?

```css
div #content {
  position: relative;
}
```

and

```css
div #share {
   position: absolute;
   top: ...;
   left: .. 
}
```